# Cannot resolve method tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

Tags: android

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(), "Home");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new CategoryFragment(), "Category");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new YouFragment(), "Settings");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Here in this above code it is show me the errror :Cannot resolve method tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

Dependencies :

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

I am new to creating android apps please friends help me to resolve this error.

Comment: You don't instantiate a variable called `tabLayout`, maybe you meant to put `tableLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);` ?

Comment: No, I have instantiated a variable called tabLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` instead of `TableLayout`.