# Unexpected implicit cast to TabLayout:layout tag was TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, material-components-android

Referred to almost all the similar type of question;didn't found the answer.

[image]

**NOTICE:**I have an error at line 26

> Cannot resolve method'setUpWithViewPager(androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager)'

Here, On `line 5`I have imported `TabLayout` and **NOT** `TableLayout`
On writing the code at `line 16` I get an unexpected error which on hovering says

> Unexpected implicit cast to TabLayout:layout tag was TableLayout

and when i change `TabLayout` to `TableLayout`
the error at `line 16` vanishes  **BUT** error at line 26 stays and as per [Cannot resolve method tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264466/cannot-resolve-method-tablayout-setupwithviewpagerviewpager)
I need to change Table Layout to Tab Layout.Which brings me to "square 1 again".

Here,is my XML file `activity_intro`

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about sharing your actual code??

Comment: You can get it you click on "Link to the error" on the second line of my question.or do you want xml files and other java classes too?(They are not related much with my question here)

Comment: Share your xml layout with question

Comment: Added! The XML file

Comment: The issue in your xml layout your should use `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` instead of `TableLayout`

Comment: Here is the XML file https://imgur.com/a/8Bnpplc and here is my java file https://imgur.com/a/MfcnsZM did i do anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot resolve method'setUpWithViewPager(androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager)'

The right method is:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

instead of

```
tabLayout.setUpWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

> implicit cast to TabLayout:layout tag was TableLayout

In your layout you have to use the component:

```
  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      ...>
     <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem/>

  </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Comment: Thanx Gabriele, replaced ```TableLayout``` with ```com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout``` and ```tabLayout.setUpWithViewPager(viewPager);``` was already in the right place...Still the same error

Comment: @KushagraBajpai are you using the `setupWithViewPager` method? (it is case sensitive, pay attention to **not** use `setUp` instead of `setup`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong method, it should be

```
tabIndicator.setupWithViewPager(screenPager);
```